# How to pass data to a form in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you pass data to a form to edit in ReactJS?

I have 3 components, Table, Form and a parent component.

```
return (
    <Table />
    <Form />
);
```

Table renders a list of items and each row has an **Edit** button

So, when the Edit button is clicked, it will call an edit function (passed from parent using props) with the id of the item.

```
this.props.edit('iAmTheIdOfTheItem');
```

The edit function will set the id in the parent component state.

```
edit = (id) => {
    this.setState({ id })
}
```

The selected item is passed to the Form component.

```
<Form item={ items.find(item => item.id === this.state.id) } />
```

This should store the current passed data in the Form component state. So that I can use that data to make any changes.

When the update button will be clicked, it will pass the state to the parent component.

**Possible Solutions**

1. componentDidMount

I can't set the state using componentDidMount since the Form component is already mounted.

2. id && < Form />

While this can help me use componentDidMount. But the problem is that the Form component is wrapped in a Modal component. So, closing animation will not work when I update the value and clear the id in the state.

3. getDerivedStateFromProps

I can use this one as a last resort but it looks like a hack to me and I'm not sure if I really need this. Since I've more than 5 forms, adding this every form does not look good to me.

Any better approach? Suggestions?

This should be helpful
https://codesandbox.io/s/82v98o21wj?fontsize=14

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue again in a different block , cuz i'm confused

Comment: Btw, Your onClick in input should be onChange

Comment: Hey, thanks. This just a dumb example to illustrate my problem. Let me update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Its not dumb , You just need to tell us what you want to achieve in a different block ,So we can focus on that

Comment: I added an answer. I guess that's what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for this.

Reference the child using `this.child = React.createRef()` and pass this to your child component like this `ref={this.child}`. Now you can use that child's functions like this `this.child.current.yourChildsFunction("object or data you want to pass")` then on that child function, just set your form state using the data passed.

Here's a complete example. Sandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmz5pn6x3y)

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.child.current.fillForm("Jackie Chan");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Child ref={this.child} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ [target.name]: target.value });
  };

  fillForm(passedvalue) {
    this.setState({ name: passedvalue });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          name="name"
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you know what? I feel like dumb. Why I did not think about ref. -_-There is always a simpler way but we just complicate things.

Comment: well I often do that too when I code until someone tells me that there are ways that will save me lots of lines :)

Answer (score 0):

Here an updated version of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jprz3449p9

The process is quite basic:

- You send the edited item to your form (via props)
- The form stores a copy in its own state
- When you change the form, it changes the local form state
- On submit, you send the state to your parent with a callback (`onUpdate` here)

What you were missing:

- Refresh the local form state when props change

  ```
  if (!item || id !== item.id) {
    this.setState(item);
  }
  ```
- Notify the parent when the item is updated with a callback

  ```
  update = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.onUpdate(this.state);
      this.setState(emptyItem);
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is the same as using getDerivedStateFromProps. But it uses an extra this.setState()